# why add a resistor parallel to voltage source?

Tags: resistors, parallel, voltage-source

Sometimes I see a resistor parallel to voltage source (such as image below), isn't it completely useless ?

Edit: I see the other similar question now, but I think it doesn't have the right keyword for this topic (I didn't find it when I searched)

[image]

Comment: and how would you propose to discharge the capacitors when the power is switched off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might change your mind if you unplugged the device and then touch the plug pins.

The 1 MΩ resistor between live and neutral provides a discharge path for the capacitor. The discharge time constant is given by $$ \tau = RC = 1M \cdot 10n = 10^6 \cdot 10^{-8} = 10^{-2} = 0.01~s $$. This is nice and fast and should prevent the user getting a surprise.